# Failure to read 'pushed' database

Tags: android, sqlite, eclipse-plugin

I'm an android developer, I'm using the questiod SQLite manager to view my database schema on eclipse indigo. So far, i have created a database successfully , i.e., it does not show me any error.

The database is created - I can see the schema , the tables and their data types (only in sqlite). Instead of manually entering the data via my app's GUI and entering the database I pulled the database and inserted a couple of rows via `insert` statements in the SQLite browser.

After successfully inserting a few rows, I saved the database and tried pushing it back.

The push is successful, I can see that the size of the database has changed but the newly pushed data base does not work.

This is what I see when I try opening it with the questiod plugin , the error I see is:

```
Error: Could not create the view: An unexpected exception was thrown.
```

**Log**

```
org.antlr.runtime.tree.RewriteEarlyExitException
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.lang.SqlParser.fk_clause(SqlParser.java:12036)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.lang.SqlParser.table_constraint_fk(SqlParser.java:11782)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.lang.SqlParser.table_constraint(SqlParser.java:11164)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.lang.SqlParser.create_table_stmt(SqlParser.java:9592)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.lang.SqlParser.schema_create_table_stmt(SqlParser.java:1102)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.schema.SqlJetSchema.parseTable(SqlJetSchema.java:288)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.schema.SqlJetSchema.readShema(SqlJetSchema.java:224)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.schema.SqlJetSchema.init(SqlJetSchema.java:117)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.schema.SqlJetSchema.<init>(SqlJetSchema.java:103)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb$2.runWithLock(SqlJetDb.java:240)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb.runWithLock(SqlJetDb.java:298)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb.readSchema(SqlJetDb.java:235)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb.refreshSchema(SqlJetDb.java:650)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb.getSchemaInternal(SqlJetDb.java:329)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.SqlJetDb.getSchema(SqlJetDb.java:324)
    at com.questoid.sqlitemanager.view.SqliteManagerView.getSqlJetSchema(SqliteManagerView.java:147)
    at com.questoid.sqlitemanager.view.SqliteManagerView.createPartControl(SqliteManagerView.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.showView(Perspective.java:2245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1145)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$20.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3921)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:3918)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:3894)
    at com.questoid.sqlitemanager.SqliteManagerPluginStartup$3$1.run(SqliteManagerPluginStartup.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4683)
    at com.questoid.sqlitemanager.SqliteManagerPluginStartup$3.run(SqliteManagerPluginStartup.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$6.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Comment: Error :Could not create the view: An unexpected exception was thrown.

Comment: Your image is missing! post a link to your image if you're not able to post image directly.

Comment: They won't let me upload and image so I have pasted the error log instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

Comment: @user1528506 You don't have enough reputation right now so you are not allowed to upload an image. You can always give a link to your image (uploaded somewhere else like in dropbox) in your question. Anyone with reputation enough will edit your post and include the picture for you. :)